# Are emission/absorption wavelengths of hydrogenic ions related to nuclear charge?

Tags: atomic-physics, spectroscopy, hydrogen, photon-emission

Is it possible to relate changing emission and absorption wavelengths of hydrogen-like ions to nuclear charge? Can one be expressed as a function of the other?

Comment: Rydberg constant? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_constant

Comment: Your question is not clear. Hydrogen ions are, in essence, positively charged protons. Do you want to know the photon emission/absorption properties  of protons without the participation of electrons?

Comment: @freecharly Apologies, there was a mistake. I meant to write hydrogenic, hydrogen-like atoms. Any ion with one electron. I'm after an expression for how changing nuclear charge affects which wavelengths are emitted and absorbed. Hydrogen and $$Li^{2+}$$ emit and absorb different wavelengths because of different energy levels, but is this difference related to the change in nuclear charge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, hydrogenic ions (those with one electron) have hydrogen-like solutions to the Schrödinger equation.

However, the potential is proportional to $Z^2$, where $Z$ is the atomic number, and the hydrogenic energy levels are multiplied by $Z^2 \mu$, where $\mu$ is the reduced mass of the electron (NB $\mu \simeq m_e$ in all cases because the nuclear mass is $\gg m_e$). Thus the energy *differences* between levels, corresponding to photon energies, will also be increased by $Z^2$.

There would also be differences in the splittings caused by spin-orbit coupling, which depends on $Z^2$ and hyperfine structure, which will depend on the nuclear spin.